# iPhone Cocoa Touch- Interface Builder elements are shifted at runtime

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Just upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2 and trying to set up an OSX project..

However, something funny is going on with Interface Builder. I feel that I am having no control over where the items that I place are ultimately being displayed. Case in point:

[image: ib problem]

How would I resolve this?

Comment: Any ideas ? It is kind of annoying trying to figure out where the items might be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was a problem with Xcode 4.3.2, downgraded to 4.3.1 and problem solved. Thanks.